# reformat laptop using a different windows disc

Tags: windows, laptop, license, reinstall

My Dad's old laptop is pretty slow and old and he got a new one, so I thought I'd reformat it and reinstall Windows. However, he can't find the original disc it came with. The laptop is currently running Windows Vista, and he only has discs for Windows XP, or the Windows 8 discs that came with his new laptop. Can I use any of them or do I need to try and find the Vista disc? (I have done this before ages ago with my old laptop, but I had the original discs then, so I don't know what happens if you use a different disc.)

Answer (score 0):

You can only install Windows Vista using a Windows Vista disc.

However, you can install a different version of Windows on your laptop if you have a spare copy laying around. Or install Linux, if you are in to that.

Comment: So you think it will work if I just use a different disc? I know that it won't be vista if I don't use a vista disc. I don't especially want vista.

Comment: Yes. Sometimes finding compatible drivers can be harder, but changing windows versions should not be that big a deal.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Windows 8 or Windows XP serial number it will work.

The laptop probably had Windows Vista OEM. The Windows Vista serial number is not going to work with a Windows 8 or Windows XP installation. From my experience it will not work with a normal version of Vista either. You will need to find a manufacturer's OEM install disc.

Comment: what does OEM mean? Can I just use a different serial number? I have a copy of Windows 7 from an old Asus laptop, it has the serial number on the package, will that work?

Comment: OEM means Original equipment manufacturer. What that means is if you had a Windows Vista OEM license on that laptop, it should stay on that machine only.

Comment: The windows 7 install/license will work great.

Comment: I thought you were asking if the vista license would work with the windows xp/8 installation.

Comment: it doesn't matter that I already used that license on my old computer?

Comment: Yes, that does matter.

Comment: That's what I thought. All of the discs I have have serial numbers, but they've all been used on other computers (although the computers they were originally for are pretty much all now broken). This is my dilemma. I don't see any way around it, I thought Dad would have the disc, but he has no idea what he's done with it.

Comment: If the old Asus computer is no longer in use, the serial number should work with your dad's computer. I'm making an assumption here, but the Asus laptop's serial is probably OEM too. The Asus installation disc may not work with your dad's computer.

Comment: @xxl3ww: Even if the old PC's no longer in use, an OEM Windows license is non-transferable.

Comment: Very true, I think Microsoft wants the OEM license to stay with the motherboard.